# Не получается убрать дубликаты в таблице, чтобы не сдивагались ячейки

Tags: excel, макросы

Есть таблица, в ней данные по дате расположены, нужно убрать повторяющиеся значения. То есть, в строке идут значения {51,09998; 51,1; 51; 51;51;51,1}
Нужно чтобы осталось 2 значения, это 51 и 51,1, остальные должны убираться.

Если использовать функцию «удаления дубликатов» то удаляются все значения и все смещается, но не должно быть так.

Может кто-то сталкивался с подобным? Как решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В свободный столбец в строку 2 вставить формулу и протянуть вниз:

```
=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($G$2:G2;G2)=1
```

Фильтр по *ИСТИНА*. Останутся видимыми строки со значениями без повторов.

Копировать диапазон, вставить на другой лист. В новую таблицу будут копированы только видимые строки.

Comment: Не получается вывести то что надо, выводятся нули

Comment: Извините, фильтрация по ИСТИНА. Исправил.